# Can not create superuser in django python admin

Tags: python, django-admin

I am new in python and I want to create a superuser for admin login, but when I type this command:
`python manage.py createsuperuser`
and enter any username with any character, python gives me this error:

```
Error: Enter a valid username.
This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.
Username (leave blank to use 'joao'):
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the username in the command arguments:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username admin
```